# Demonstrate basic property of Hermitian

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics

I want to demonstrate that  $(A|v\rangle)^* = \langle v|A^*$

Given only this $(AB)^*=A^*B^*$ and $(|v\rangle, A|w\rangle) = (A^*|v\rangle, |w\rangle)$
Is it possible?

The difficulty is that i don't know how to maniuplate $\langle v|A^*$.

Also: Should I assume that 
$A|v\rangle = |v_1\rangle$, is $|v_1\rangle^* = \langle v_1|$
or should I also conjugate the vector (and not only take the transposal)?

(I'm reading Nielsen's book: Quantum computation and quantum information)

Comment: Isn't $(AB)^*=B^* A^*$ when $X^*$ is the adjoint of $X$?

Comment: Yes, X* is the adjoint of X if X is Hermitian.